# Conditionally Adding Class then Setting it Permanently in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class, ng-init

This may be an odd question, but it would be of great use to me if what I'm asking is possible.  Is there a way to set a class using a conditional statement, then freezing that class onto the element?

This is what I'd like to do -  If an element has the text value of `'somestring[A]'`, I would like to style this element to the class `greenify` based on the final three characters.  I would then like to change the value of the string to `'somestring'` and keep the `greenify` class on it.  Note that I am aware I can display this string differently, but for my case actually changing the string is much preferred.

I have a way I could implement this in my mind, but it would be much cleaner and clearer if there was an angular way to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is do you need the value of the class to change after the initial change? If not, you could set up a custom watch on the value, and then unwatch it after the change. By unwatching it the class binding won't update in the DOM.

```
var unWatch = $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
  // set class on element

  unwatch();
});
```

If you need the value to update again and set the class, you can add the watch back on and unwatch when needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer, but not a good fit for my problem.  I am looking into it and will post results when I figure this out.

Comment: Do you have an example on JSFiddle or Plunkr I could look at to get a better context of the problem?

Comment: It's a biggie!  The issue is that I have a complex data structure and don't know what 'myVar' looks like.  I've created a directive and almost have it working - I'll post it here when I'm done

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with for my custom circumstance using a directive.  I hope it helps someone.

```
.directive('colorByChange', function(){
    return {
        scope: {test: '=passedValue'},
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.ready(function(){
                var txt = scope.test;
                switch (txt.slice(-3, txt.length)) {
                    case '[A]':
                        element.addClass('greenify');
                        element.text(scope.test.slice(0, -3));
                        break;
                    case '[U]':
                        element.addClass('bluify');
                        element.text(scope.test.slice(0, -3));
                        break;
                    case '[D]':
                        element.addClass('redify');
                        element.text(scope.test.slice(0, -3));
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="handle in brand.handles" color-by-change passed-value="handle">
  {{handle}}
</span>
```